# Depth First Search in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, infinite-loop

I'm trying to implement depth first search in SQLite:
I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE table1(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ,id_parrent INTEGER ,id_child INTEGER );

INSERT INTO table1(id_parrent,id_child) VALUES('1','4');
INSERT INTO table1(id_parrent,id_child) VALUES('1','1');
INSERT INTO table1(id_parrent,id_child) VALUES('1','3');
INSERT INTO table1(id_parrent,id_child) VALUES('1','2');
INSERT INTO table1(id_parrent,id_child) VALUES('2','8');
INSERT INTO table1(id_parrent,id_child) VALUES('2','7');
INSERT INTO table1(id_parrent,id_child) VALUES('2','3');
INSERT INTO table1(id_parrent,id_child) VALUES('2','6');
INSERT INTO table1(id_parrent,id_child) VALUES('2','10');
INSERT INTO table1(id_parrent,id_child) VALUES('2','5');
INSERT INTO table1(id_parrent,id_child) VALUES('2','9');
INSERT INTO table1(id_parrent,id_child) VALUES('2','2');
```

and I attempted a depth first search with the following query:

```
WITH RECURSIVE
 under_parrent(id_child,level) AS (
  VALUES('1','0')
UNION ALL
SELECT table1.id_child, under_parrent.level+1
  FROM table1,under_parrent 
  WHERE table1.id_parrent = under_parrent.id_child
 ORDER BY 2 DESC
 )
SELECT id_child FROM under_parrent;
```

My problem is that the result is looping infinitely, as shown in this picture:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your second record connects `1` to itself; the query correctly reports this infinite loop.

Normally, avoiding duplicates is done by using `UNION` instead of `UNION ALL`, but this will not work in this case because the `level` value is different.
You have to filter out those loops in the `WHERE` (`table1.id_parrent <> table1.id_child`), but this is not easily possible if there is a larger loop (such as 1 → 2 → 1).